# Bootstrap theme doesn't charge with flask

Tags: python, html, twitter-bootstrap, flask, web-applications

I'm start approach to Flask and Bootstrap someone can tell me why bottstrap doesn't charge?
I am sure there is an obvious solution but I am stuck all morning

app.py: this is the script typed

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

index.html: this is the HTML that I think it's compatible with Flask

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Python Flask Bucket List App</title>


    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Sign In</a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="showSignUp">Sign Up</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <h3 class="text-muted">Python Flask App</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Bucket List App</h1>
            <p class="lead"></p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="showSignUp" role="button">Sign up today</a>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="row marketing">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h4>Bucket List</h4>
                <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>

                <h4>Bucket List</h4>
                <p>Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>

                <h4>Bucket List</h4>
                <p>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h4>Bucket List</h4>
                <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>

                <h4>Bucket List</h4>
                <p>Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>

                <h4>Bucket List</h4>
                <p>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <footer class="footer">
            <p>&copy; Company 2015</p>
        </footer>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Data Structure:

FlaskApp(templates(index.html)app.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bootstrap link does not work. Try using this link instead

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

There are many ways to include Bootstrap CSS, check out the documentation for more.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/